# Adding coffeescript unit tests to rails 4 project aborting rake

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, jasmine

I am trying to add unit testing for javascript assets in ruby on rails 4 project using jasmine-rails gem. I managed to add the gem to gem file, installing gems successfully, but I failed to build the project.

Test part of Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # Haml generators for views, remove this line to generate erb views
  gem 'haml-rails'
end
```

Testing specs in Rakefile:

```
task 'rails:spec' do
    sh "cd rails-root && rake spec"
end

task 'javascript:spec' do
    sh "cd rails-root && bundle exec rake spec:javascript"
end

task :test => ['rails:spec', 'javascript:spec']
```

It's failing with the following trace:

```
rake aborted! Missing template jasmine_rails/spec_runner/index, jasmine_rails/application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:   * "SOME_DIRECTORY/rails-root/app/views"   * "SOME_OTHER_DIRECTORY/ruby2.1.x/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jasmine-rails-0.12.2/app/views"
```

Any clue?